# Internationalization (i18n) using JSF Facelets: Messages in Java-classes

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, facelets

I have successfully implemented i18n in my project. Now I'm stuck in my Bean...

```
private String pageTitle;
public List<Product> getProductsByCategory(String category) {
  if(validate(category)) {
    pageTitle = category;
    return service.getProductsByCategory(String category);
  } else {
    pageTitle = "Random products";
    return service.getRandomProducts();
  }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to let my pageTitle depend on the result of the provided method. All fine, but this is not fine considering internationalization. I have tried using a Properties.load(new FileInputStream) approach, but this does not work considering the files are name base.properties, base_en_US.properties and so on.

Does anyone know the best practice in this kind of situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the same way as JSF is under the covers using to load resource bundles: using the [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API. Here's an example assuming that the base name is `com.example.i18n.base` (exactly the value as you'd use in `<f:loadBundle>` in view or `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml`)

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.i18n.base",
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
String pageTitle = bundle.getString("page.title");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC! This is EXACTLY what I has looking for!